# Delete words using regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

How can I remove the `SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS*: ONLY impacted versions are listed.` line from the text?

```
text = (
  'SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS*: ONLY impacted versions are listed.HP-UX B.11.00, B.11.11, and B.11.22.',
  'SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS*: ONLY impacted versions are listed.HP-UX B.11.00, B.11.04, B.11.11 running',
  'SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS*: ONLY impacted versions are listed.HP-UX B.11.11 and B.11.23'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string replace function in python. [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
toRemove = "SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS*: ONLY impacted versions are listed."
modifiedText = tuple(map(lambda x: x.replace(toRemove, ''), text))
```

Note: You can use the replace function in the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library to use regex.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need regex, just a simple `replace` function:

```
text = tuple(item.replace("SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS*: ONLY impacted versions are listed.", "") 
       for item in text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` since it is easier.

```py
text = text.replace("SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS*: ONLY impacted versions are listed.", "")
```

But if you really want a regex to do this job for you (which I do not recommend on this particular case), you can do:

```py
text = "SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS*: ONLY impacted versions are listed.HP-UX B.11.00, B.11.11, and B.11.22."
text = re.sub("SUPPORTED SOFTWARE VERSIONS\*: ONLY impacted versions are listed\.", "", text)
# 'HP-UX B.11.00, B.11.11, and B.11.22.'
```